# Issue with patindex and unicode character '-'

Tags: sql-server, unicode, patindex

I have a string called `Dats` which is either of the general appearence `xxxx-nnnnn` (where `x` is a character, and `n` is a number) or `nnn-nnnnnn`.

I want to return only the numbers.

For this I've tried:

```
SELECT Distinct dats, 
Left(SubString(artikelnr, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', artikelnr), 8000), PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(artikelnr, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', artikelnr), 8000) + 'X')-1)
FROM ThatDatabase
```

It is *almost* what I want. It removes the regular characters `x`, but it does not remove the unicode character `-`. How can I remove this as well? And also, it seems rather ineffective to have two `PatIndex` functions for every row, is there a way to avoid this? (This will be used on a big database where the result of this Query will be used as keys).

EDIT: Updated as a new database sometimes contained additional `-`'s or `.` together with `-`.

```
DECLARE @T as table
(
    dats nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('111BWA30'),
('115-200-11')
('115-22.4-1')
('10.000.22')
('600F-FFF200')
```

Comment: The query you posted is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't sure if you wanted the numbers before the `-` char as well, but if you do, here is one way to do it:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as table
(
    dats nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('abcde-1234'),
('23-343')
```

The query:

```
SELECT  dats,
        case when patindex('%[^0-9]-[0-9]%', dats) > 0 then
            right(dats, len(dats) - patindex('%-[0-9]%', dats))
        else
            stuff(dats, charindex('-', dats), 1, '')
        end As NumbersOnly
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
dats        NumbersOnly
abcde-1234  1234
23-343      23343
```

If you want the only the numbers to the right of the `-` char, it's simpler:

```
SELECT  dats,
        right(dats, len(dats) - patindex('%-[0-9]%', dats)) As RightNumbersOnly
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
dats        RightNumbersOnly
abcde-1234  1234
23-343      343
```

Comment: I want to remove any characters and `-` values from the string so only the integers are left. I see that this function does that. Id like to ask however, seeing as this worked so good I tested it on Another database which would have the same appaerence, but I see now that it sometimes contains more than one `-`, or sometimes `.` as well as `-`. Is there any neat way to adjust for this? Will update the OP soon with a sample table.

Comment: You are correct. It too big of an alteration to have as an edit. Accepting your answer, and might consider using my "edit" as a later question after I've thought some time more of it. Thanks again for a wonderful, clear, and thought-through answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which characters you need to remove then use `REPLACE` function

```
DECLARE @T as table
(
    dats nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES
('111BWA30'),
('115-200-11'),
('115-22.4-1'),
('10.000.22'),
('600F-FFF200')

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(dats, '.', ''), '-', '')
FROM @T
```